# Windows laptop uses Wifi access point but Android smartphone claims it is connected but can't access Internet

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

This is a repost of [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14968/1097) at Android SE.

There's an Asus 240 MIMO Wifi access point. There's a laptop running Windows XP that uses that access point no problem for years so far. And there's an Android based HTC Desire S smartphone that has problems. The objective is to make the smartphone access the Internet via the Wifi access point.

I open "wireless networks" configuration pane, "enable" Wifi - it goes through "scanning" and "obtaining IP address" stages, says "connected to TheRightNetworkName". The Wifi symbol is displayed in the bar under the top of the screen. Yet when I try to open any page in a browser if wouldn't do so and claim there were problems accessing that page.

I tried the following (listed in [this answer below](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14968/windows-laptop-uses-wifi-access-point-but-android-smartphone-claims-it-is-connec/14980#14980), thanks to [user Matthew Read](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/1465/matthew-read)):

- rebooted the phone - doesn't help
- checked MAC filtering on the AP - it is disabled
- disabled the firewall on the AP - doesn't help
- tried to change channels - doesn't help, the AP has 13 channels if that matters
- tried to change to 2.4 GHz - looks like it is already the only option, couldn't find any way to change the range
- didn't try to switch from WPA that is currently used to WEP because it feels quite scary - I can mess things up
- tried switching modes - b, g, b/g - doesn't help

Also tried to [ping the smarphone IP from the laptop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14968/windows-laptop-uses-wifi-access-point-but-android-smartphone-claims-it-is-connec/14983#14983) - the ping is okay.

The same smartphone works okay on two other WPA-protected networks okay, the problem is only on that network.

How do I debug and resolve this issue?

Comment: Is the windows laptop routing the packets? If not you have a working connection between the phone and the laptop, and one between the laptop and the Internet. But no forwarding between those.

Answer (score 0):

So you've happily disabled the firewall on it ok, yet changing from WPA to WEP seems scary?!

Disabling WEP would be one of the first things i would try after disabling MAC filtering... Have you also added the phones MAC into the filters? I don't know the Galaxy S but check there's no proxy settings set...